# "42V18" "ERROR 2848: Could not determine data type of parameter $1"

Tags: odbc, vertica

My application connecting to vertica DB using ODBC connection. It failing with below

```
"42V18"  "ERROR 2848:  Could not determine data type of parameter $1"
```

I am passing string value to the parameter. Any idea how to resolve this error

Comment: Care to post the actual code that causes the error, including the SQL statement?

Comment: ... and maybe the relevant ODBC traces if possible...

Comment: We can't answer like this. I suppose you are trying to execute a statement with a parameter marker , like `INSERT INTO foo VALUES (?,?)` or similar. Can you share the statement *and* the target table's definition with us?

Comment: Here my statement is    SELECT DROP_PARTITION(?,?)